# IDM Prevents downloading a file through a windows application, and catch it

Tags: c#, windows, webclient

I have a Windows application and I try to download a file, in the code like this:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(myWebUrlFile, myLocalFilePath);
}
```

But, when i run it, Internet Download Manager(IDM) runs and, Prevents downloading automatically. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LiWx.png)

do you have any idea?

Comment: Uninstall IDM ?

Comment: :) And how about when I developed it and delivered to the customer?

Comment: Tell them to not install useless tools? Sorry, but if somebody installs tools that hijack your download, there is little you can do but to tell them to uninstall this crap.

Comment: They need both programs

Comment: I find that hard to believe. "Download Manager" is something people dropped with their modems. But anyway... you will need to find out how that tool hijacks your download and then find a way around. Maybe start by downloading to a byte array instead of file.

Comment: What if the user simply clicks "No"? That should do it, shouldn't it?

Comment: It is true
But can not this message be displayed at all?

Comment: You will have to ask the programmer of this tool. Nobody here knows *what exactly* that tool hijacks *now* or what it *might* hijack in the future.

Comment: @nvoigt Don't forget that not everyone is on a stable or fast internet connection, so download managers can still be useful. The location might be in the middle of a forest or on an oil platform, where shoddy satellite internet is the only option.

Comment: @cost Well, it seems stable enough that the OP does *not* want a download manager :)

Answer (score 0):

Yesssssssss. It works :)
thank you so much @nvoight.

for downloading to a byte array instead of file,
I change my code like this:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] fileBytesBuffer = client.DownloadData(myWebUrlFile)
    File.WriteAllBytes(myLocalFilePath, fileBytesBuffer);       
}
```

now IDM cannot catch it.

Comment: A caveat: while it may solve this particular problem, do not adopt this as a general technique -- `DownloadFile` is optimized to efficiently transfer network data onto the disk, without first filling the whole of memory with it. I'd keep this in reserve for when you actually need to trick download managers specifically.

Comment: Thanks. @Jeroen-Mostert